# How to reset an HTML table to its original after changing it with a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

So basically, I've a javascript function, that changes the `<section>` in which this table is to show the coordinates of the mouse on a button, and I need it to change back to the HTML table when the mouse comes off the button.

HTML:

```
 <section class = "table">
                    <table id = "table">
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan = "3">Table Data</th>
                        </tr> 

                        <tbody>                            
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan = "2">1</td>  
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>  
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                    </tr>   
                    <tr>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td rowspan = "2">7</td>
                        <td>8</td>    
                    </tr> 
                    <tr>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                    </tr>
                        </tbody>

                        <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td>11</td>      
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td rowspan = "2">13</td>
                    </tr>  
                    <tr>
                        <td>14</td>    
                        <td>15</tf>
                    </tr> 
                </tfoot>    
                    </table>    
                </section>
```

Javascript:

```
function displayCoordinates(e){        
    table.innerHTML = "MouseX: " + e.offsetX + "<br>" + "MouseY: " + e.offsetY;
}

function resetTable(){

}
```

Comment: Please also add the code for the reset function or what you have tried to solve the problem, otherwise it‘s just asking „could you please code for me“ and that would be offtopic and the question should be closed. Hint: You should store the base tabel values temporarily and use these variable values in the reset function...

Answer (score 1):

Clone the table at the start. Then append it afterward.

```
var tablDom = document.queryselector('table').clone(),
      wrapperDom = document.queryselectorAll('.table')[0];

function displayCoordinates(e){
  table.innerHTML = "MouseX: " + e.offsetX + "<br>" + "MouseY: " + e.offsetY;
}
function resetTable(){
  wrapperDom.appendChild(tableDom);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be done by saving the original html string.

```
var originalHTML = table.innerHTML
function displayCoordinates(e){
  table.innerHTML = "MouseX: " + e.offsetX + "<br>" + "MouseY: " + e.offsetY;
}
function resetTable(){
  table.innerHTML = originalHTML
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks heaps, that saved me so much time.